# TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails + angularJS, trying to insert data into multiple level (nested) tables, here's my controller code, (Model relations: Wines has Awards, Campaigns & Promotions through Campaigns)

```
params.fetch(:wine).permit(:wine_name, :terroir, :vintage, :bottle_size, :size_unit, :description, 
             :campaigns_attributes => [:id, :campaign_name, :start_date, :end_date, :quantity, :campaign_price, :regular_price, :status, :created_date, :wines_id, 
               :promotions_attributes => [:id, :campaign_id, :discount_value, :discount_type, :discount_off, :quantity, :quantity_unit]], 
             :awards_attributes => [:id, :wines_id, :title, :description, :award_date, :image])
```

getting error "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (`ActiveRecord: 0.0ms`)"

```
Processing by Admin::Api::WinesController# create as JSON
Parameters: {
  "wine" => {
    "wine_name" => "Name",
    "terroir" => "Terroir",
    "vintage" => "2010",
    "bottle_size" => "12",
    "size_unit" => "ml",
    "description" => "EDesc",
    "award" => {
      "title" => "Title",
      "description" => "Desc",
      "award_date" => "2016-11-01"
    },
    "campaign" => {
      "start_date" => "2016-11-01",
      "end_date" => "2016-11-25",
      "quantity" => "12",
      "campaign_price" => "12",
      "regular_price" => "12",
      "status" => 0,
      "created_date" => ""
    },
    "promotions" => [{
      "discount_value" => "1", "discount_type" => "%", "discount_off" => "Off Subtotal", "quantity" => "1", "quantity_unit" => "bottle"
    }, {
      "discount_value" => "2", "discount_type" => "%", "discount_off" => "Off Subtotal", "quantity" => "2", "quantity_unit" => "bottles"
    }]
  }
}
```

In rails console data is getting displayed as above, but throwing me error saying, "*TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):*"

What error i'm doing, also is the controller part correct for inserting data into nested tables?

Comment: Read the log. Find out the line that raises the error. On that line you are likely to use array as a hash (you think it's a hash, but it's actually an array)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The log says error in this line, `@wine = Wine.new(all_params)` where `all_params` is the private method for the `param.fetch()` line in the controller file, the promotions data are in array, do i need to handle it differently.

Comment: It's clear that you need to do _something_ differently, since the current way doesn't work. As to what to change, I can't say. Too little details.